# FB login using Swift

Tags: swift, fbsdk

I was following this tutorial

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios.

I am in step 5. I'm trying to convert

```
BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
openURL:url
sourceApplication:sourceApplication
annotation:annotation
```

to swift, Here's what i did

```
        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication], annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

    return handled
```

[image: error img]

I tried another

```
 let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication://no idea what to put here , annotation: //and here)
```

How to resolve this issue?

P.S. I am a newbie in swift, just want to share a site  where it could help [https://objectivec2swift.com](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main) converting from obj-C to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on Facebook login too. And the problem is here there are two very similar methods. The correct one for Facebook login is your second method which should look like this;

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                          annotation: [:])
```

By the way if you're a beginner like me i suggest you to subscribe and watch LetsBuildThatApp channel on Youtube. There is a tuttorial for Facebook Log-in too.

Have nice coding.

Comment: Thank you the error is now gone! Thanks for the help. ps I've seen his videos too. I am working in fb login with core data now

Comment: I'm glad that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

**Just write this -**

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
    {

       return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! but this code says unresolved identifier. Tnx again